# Fancybox custom div show/hide

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, fancybox

I have a custom post type in Wordpress that creates a gallery of images (unordered list) that open in fancybox. I created a dynamic div of a sold label within the fancybox JavaScript that appears on the left corner of the image in the lightbox across from the close button. I only want the label to show if the image is within the category "sold". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide any information or code of your Wordpress, for example your front-end code or your custom post type code?

Comment: To create the button I added this code within the FancyBox Javascript:
`// Create a label
 if (current.label) {
  $(current.tpl.label).appendTo(F.skin).bind('click.fb', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  });
  }

label : '<div class="sold-label"><h2>Sold</h2></div>',`

Comment: perhaps there is a way to look for a class on the front end and if that class is present display the label div? I tried below but it didn't work.
`if ($("#fancybox-title").hasClass("sold")) {`
       `$("#sold-label").css("display", "block");`
      `}`
I'm adding a class to the fancybox title like this:
`class="fancybox-title <?php theme_get_categories($post->ID, 'gallery_category', ' ', 'slug'); ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, I figured this out on my own. I added the category slug to the fancybox link class like this:
`<?php theme_get_categories($post->ID, 'gallery_category', ' ', 'slug'); ?>`

Then I created a fancybox helper for that class in my javascript file that creates a new wrapper for that class like this:

`tpl: {
  wrap     : '<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-image fancybox-opened" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div id="sold-label" class="sold-label"><h2>Sold</h2></div><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>'
 },`